# Stream mp4 videos in different languages (ExpressJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video, ffmpeg

I use the following code to stream videos (just in my local network). In my mp4 files are several audio tracks with different languages. Is it possible to select a specific audio track to stream? For example, that you specify a language as query parameter in the URL, and the streamed video has the selected audio track.

Example 1: 
URL: "localhost/video?lang=en" 
Video: English audio track

Example 2: 
URL: "localhost/video?lang=de" 
Video: German audio track

Maybe you can remove all unneeded audio tracks in the stream with ffmpeg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)?

Working expressjs **code**/example:
https://betterprogramming.pub/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6
(https://gist.github.com/BetterProgramming/3bf5d66b0285a2690de684d46c4cabb4#file-app-get-js)

Comment: Yes, it looks to be possible. You can use `URL` to get the selected language in the `?lang= -- `. Possibly helpful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Yes, only I don't know how to modify the audio tracks in the mp4 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are trivial way to do it:

0. Design your express api to handle query params, such as **?lang=%lang%**
1. Use [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) to select track you need.

Unfortunatelly, API of HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks has no rich support in browsers, so the best and clear way to solve your issue is export and upload your videos in all langs you need and send file with current audio-track on current lang wich is defined in query param, like this:

```
app.get('%YOUR_API_ENDPOINT%', function(req, res) {
    const lang =req.params.lang        
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + `/my_file_${lang}.mp4`));
});
```